# Harmattan Conky on 14.04 with Variety wallpaper, Conky border stays as old wallpaper

Tags: unity, compiz, themes, desktop-background, conky

It seems like this would be a common problem, yet I don't see any mention of it. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04/Unity. I have Variety installed and set to change the desktop image every 10 minutes. The 1st few times the desktop image changes, the conky border changes after a 5 second delay( from old image to new image). But then, by the 5th or 6th desktop image refresh, the conky border will no longer change with image and therefore I get this result: [image: Conky Harmattan]

The Orange border/frame is actually left over from the previous image. I've tried resizing border etc, thinking that this was a transparency issue. But I haven't found a fix yet. Here's my Conky rc:

```
# Conky settings #
background yes
update_interval 1
double_buffer yes
no_buffers yes
imlib_cache_size 10

# Window specifications #
gap_x 40
gap_y 40
minimum_size 268 620
maximum_width 268
own_window yes
own_window_type override  # other options are: override/dock/desktop/panel
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorate,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,below
border_inner_margin 0
border_outer_margin 0
alignment top_right
#own_window_argb_visual yes
#own_window_argb_value 0

# Graphics settings #
draw_shades no
default_shade_color AAAAAA
draw_outline no
default_outline_color AAAAAA
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no
default_graph_size 26 80
show_graph_scale no
show_graph_range no

# Text settings #
use_xft yes
xftalpha 0
xftfont Droid Sans:size=8
text_buffer_size 256
override_utf8_locale yes

# Useful shortenings #
short_units yes
pad_percents 2
top_name_width 7

# Color scheme #
default_color F9F9F9
color1 FFFFFF
color2 F9F9F9
color3 F9F9F9
color4 F9F9F9
color5 DCDCDC
color6 F9F9F9
color7 F9F9F9
color8 F9F9F9
color9 666666

TEXT
# Various images #
${execi 300 curl -s "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2418046&u=f" -o ~/.cache/weather.xml}
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/shadow.png -p 4,14 -s 260x591}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/fav-color-1.png -p 20,30 -s 228x61}\
${execi 300 cp -f ~/.conky-weather/icons/weather-photos-7/$(grep "yweather:condition" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*").png ~/.cache/weather.png}${image ~/.cache/weather.png -p 20,91 -s 228x86}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/fav-color-3.png -p 20,177 -s 228x86}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/fav-color-4.png -p 20,263 -s 228x105}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/fav-color-5.png -p 20,368 -s 228x105}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/fav-color-6.png -p 20,473 -s 228x119}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/fav-color-7.png -p 20,478 -s 228x14}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/separator-v.png -p 95,177 -s 1x92}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/separator-v.png -p 172,177 -s 1x92}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/separator-h.png -p 18,369 -s 232x1}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/separator-h.png -p 18,269 -s 232x1}\
\
# The days of the forecast #
\
${color3}${voffset 172}${alignc 77}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "day=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==1' | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'}${color}
${color3}${voffset -13}${alignc}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "day=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==2' | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'}${color}
${color3}${voffset -13}${alignc -77}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "day=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==3' | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'}${color}
\
# The temperatures of the forecast #
\
${color2}${voffset 51}${alignc 77}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "low=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==1'}°/${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "high=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==1'}°${color}
${color2}${voffset -13}${alignc}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "low=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==2'}°/${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "high=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==2'}°${color}
${color2}${voffset -13}${alignc -77}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "low=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==3'}°/${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "high=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==3'}°${color}
\
# The "conditions" section of the conky #
\
${goto 36}${voffset -172}${font Droid Sans :size=36}${color1}${execi 300 grep "yweather:condition" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "temp=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"}°${font}${color}
${goto 46}${voffset 14}${font Droid Sans :size=12}${color1}${execi 300 grep "yweather:condition" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "text=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"}${font}${color}
${color1}${alignr 52}${voffset -73}${execi 300 grep "yweather:atmosphere" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "pressure=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"} ${execi 300 grep "yweather:units" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "pressure=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"}
${color1}${alignr 52}${voffset 7}${execi 300 grep "yweather:atmosphere" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "humidity=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"} %${color}
${color1}${alignr 52}${voffset 7}${execi 300 grep "yweather:wind" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "speed=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"} ${execi 300 grep "yweather:units" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "speed=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"}${color}
\
# Clock + calendar #
\
${voffset -117}${font Droid Sans Mono :size=22}${alignc}${color2}${time %H:%M}${font}${color}
${voffset 4}${font Droid Sans :size=10}${alignc}${color6}${time %A, %B %d}${font}${color}
\
# Cpu, memory, uptime, and load graph #
\
${voffset 294}${goto 40}${color2}Cpu:${color}
${voffset 4}${goto 40}${color2}Mem:${color}
${voffset 4}${goto 40}${color2}Uptime:${color}
${voffset -47}${alignr 39}${color2}${cpu cpu0}%${color}
${voffset 4}${alignr 39}${color2}${memperc}%${color}
${voffset 4}${alignr 39}${color2}${uptime_short}${color}
${voffset -47}${alignc}${color2}${cpubar 5,36}${color}
${voffset 4}${alignc}${color2}${membar 5,36}${color}
${voffset 29}${goto 40}${loadgraph 26,190 F9F9F9 F9F9F9 -l}
\
# The processes section #
\
${voffset 26}${goto 40}${color2}${top_mem name 1}${color}
${voffset 4}${goto 40}${color2}${top_mem name 2}${color}
${voffset 4}${goto 40}${color2}${top_mem name 3}${color}
${voffset 4}${goto 40}${color2}${top_mem name 4}${color}
${voffset 4}${goto 40}${color2}${top_mem name 5}${color}
${voffset -81}${alignc}${color5}${top_mem mem 1}%${color}
${voffset 4}${alignc}${color5}${top_mem mem 2}%${color}
${voffset 4}${alignc}${color5}${top_mem mem 3}%${color}
${voffset 4}${alignc}${color5}${top_mem mem 4}%${color}
${voffset 4}${alignc}${color5}${top_mem mem 5}%${color}
${voffset -81}${alignr 39}${color6}${top_mem mem_res 1}${color}
${voffset 4}${alignr 39}${color6}${top_mem mem_res 2}${color}
${voffset 4}${alignr 39}${color6}${top_mem mem_res 3}${color}
${voffset 4}${alignr 39}${color6}${top_mem mem_res 4}${color}
${voffset 4}${alignr 39}${color6}${top_mem mem_res 5}${color}
${voffset -104}${goto 40}${color9}Proc${color}
${voffset -13}${alignc}${color9}Mem%${color}
${voffset -13}${alignr 39}${color9}Mem${color}
\
# The network section #
\
${if_existing /proc/net/route ppp0}
${voffset -227}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed ppp0}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed ppp0}
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph ppp0 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph ppp0 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup ppp0}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown ppp0}
${else}
${if_existing /proc/net/route ppp1}
${voffset -240}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed ppp1}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed ppp1}
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph ppp1 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph ppp1 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup ppp1}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown ppp1}
${else}
${if_existing /proc/net/route wlp2s1}
${voffset -253}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed wlp2s1}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed wlp2s1}
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph wlp2s1 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph wlp2s1 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup wlp2s1}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown wlp2s1}
${else}
${if_existing /proc/net/route wlp2s0}
${voffset -266}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed wlp2s0}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed wlp2s0}
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph wlp2s0 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph wlp2s0 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup wlp2s0}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown wlp2s0}
${else}
${if_existing /proc/net/route wlan0}
${voffset -279}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed wlan0}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed wlan0}
${voffset 8}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph wlan0 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph wlan0 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup wlan0}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown wlan0}
${else}
${if_existing /proc/net/route wlan1}
${voffset -292}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed wlan1}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed wlan1}
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph wlan1 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph wlan1 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup wlan1}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown wlan1}
${else}
${if_existing /proc/net/route eth1}
${voffset -305}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed eth1}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed eth1}
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph eth1 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph eth1 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup eth1}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown eth1}
${else}
${if_existing /proc/net/route eth0}
${voffset -318}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed eth0}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed eth0}
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph eth0 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph eth0 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup eth0}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown eth0}
${else}
${if_existing /proc/net/route enp0s0}
${voffset -331}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed enp0s0}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed enp0s0}
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph enp0s0 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph enp0s0 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup enp0s0}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown enp0s0}
${else}
${if_existing /proc/net/route enp0s1}
${voffset -344}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed enp0s1}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed enp0s1}
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph enp0s1 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph enp0s1 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup enp0s1}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown enp0s1}
${else}
${voffset -311}${goto 40}${color5}Network disconnected${color}
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/offline.png -p 44,284 -s 16x16}
${endif}${endif}${endif}${endif}${endif}${endif}${endif}${endif}${endif}${endif}
\
# Various images including the icons of the forecast #
\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/pressure2.png -p 224,95 -s 16x16}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/humidity2.png -p 224,115 -s 16x16}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/wind.png -p 224,136 -s 16x16}\
${execi 300 cp -f ~/.conky-weather/icons/weather-icons-light/$(grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==1').png ~/.cache/weather-1.png}${image ~/.cache/weather-1.png -p 41,207 -s 32x32}\
${execi 300 cp -f ~/.conky-weather/icons/weather-icons-light/$(grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==2').png ~/.cache/weather-2.png}${image ~/.cache/weather-2.png -p 119,207 -s 32x32}\
${execi 300 cp -f ~/.conky-weather/icons/weather-icons-light/$(grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==3').png ~/.cache/weather-3.png}${image ~/.cache/weather-3.png -p 195,207 -s 32x32}${font}${voffset -120}\
```

EDIT: I deleted # from

```
#own_window_argb_visual yes
    #own_window_argb_value 0
```

However, I now have a thick black border. Is it not possible to just have "actual" transparency, or else get rid of border?

[image: Conky with Border]

EDIT 2: 
This is the closest I've gotten to what I'm trying to achieve. I changed

`own_window_type` to Dock(from override)

and deleted "#" from

```
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_argb_value 0
```

Changing to "Dock" meant I had to change 
Gap_x to 1600 (to get it positioned right)
I no longer have border, but now the actual conky is too transparent. When I have a dark desktop picture, the conky is visible. But light background, and it's too transparent.
[image: Conky with "dock" setting]

I've tried deleting own_window_transparent yes (this did nothing)
As well as changing arg value to 255 (gave me black border)
Logging out between each change.
Here is my conky rc now

```
# Conky settings #
background yes
update_interval 1
double_buffer yes
no_buffers yes
imlib_cache_size 10

# Window specifications #
gap_x 1600
gap_y 40
minimum_size 268 620
maximum_width 268
own_window yes
own_window_type dock  # other options are: override/dock/desktop/panel
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorate,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,below
border_inner_margin 0
border_outer_margin 0
alignment top_right
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_argb_value 0

# Graphics settings #
draw_shades no
default_shade_color AAAAAA
draw_outline no
default_outline_color AAAAAA
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no
default_graph_size 26 80
show_graph_scale no
show_graph_range no

# Text settings #
use_xft yes
xftalpha 0
xftfont Droid Sans:size=8
text_buffer_size 256
override_utf8_locale yes

# Useful shortenings #
short_units yes
pad_percents 2
top_name_width 7

# Color scheme #
default_color F9F9F9
color1 FFFFFF
color2 F9F9F9
color3 F9F9F9
color4 F9F9F9
color5 DCDCDC
color6 F9F9F9
color7 F9F9F9
color8 F9F9F9
color9 666666

TEXT
# Various images #
${execi 300 curl -s "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2418046&u=f" -o ~/.cache/weather.xml}
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/shadow.png -p 4,14 -s 260x591}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/fav-color-1.png -p 20,30 -s 228x61}\
${execi 300 cp -f ~/.conky-weather/icons/weather-photos-7/$(grep "yweather:condition" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*").png ~/.cache/weather.png}${image ~/.cache/weather.png -p 20,91 -s 228x86}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/fav-color-3.png -p 20,177 -s 228x86}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/fav-color-4.png -p 20,263 -s 228x105}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/fav-color-5.png -p 20,368 -s 228x105}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/fav-color-6.png -p 20,473 -s 228x119}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/fav-color-7.png -p 20,478 -s 228x14}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/separator-v.png -p 95,177 -s 1x92}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/separator-v.png -p 172,177 -s 1x92}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/separator-h.png -p 18,369 -s 232x1}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/separator-h.png -p 18,269 -s 232x1}\
\
# The days of the forecast #
\
${color3}${voffset 172}${alignc 77}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "day=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==1' | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'}${color}
${color3}${voffset -13}${alignc}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "day=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==2' | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'}${color}
${color3}${voffset -13}${alignc -77}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "day=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==3' | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'}${color}
\
# The temperatures of the forecast #
\
${color2}${voffset 51}${alignc 77}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "low=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==1'}°/${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "high=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==1'}°${color}
${color2}${voffset -13}${alignc}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "low=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==2'}°/${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "high=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==2'}°${color}
${color2}${voffset -13}${alignc -77}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "low=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==3'}°/${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "high=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==3'}°${color}
\
# The "conditions" section of the conky #
\
${goto 36}${voffset -172}${font Droid Sans :size=36}${color1}${execi 300 grep "yweather:condition" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "temp=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"}°${font}${color}
${goto 46}${voffset 14}${font Droid Sans :size=12}${color1}${execi 300 grep "yweather:condition" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "text=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"}${font}${color}
${color1}${alignr 52}${voffset -73}${execi 300 grep "yweather:atmosphere" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "pressure=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"} ${execi 300 grep "yweather:units" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "pressure=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"}
${color1}${alignr 52}${voffset 7}${execi 300 grep "yweather:atmosphere" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "humidity=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"} %${color}
${color1}${alignr 52}${voffset 7}${execi 300 grep "yweather:wind" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "speed=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"} ${execi 300 grep "yweather:units" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "speed=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"}${color}
\
# Clock + calendar #
\
${voffset -117}${font Droid Sans Mono :size=22}${alignc}${color2}${time %H:%M}${font}${color}
${voffset 4}${font Droid Sans :size=10}${alignc}${color6}${time %A, %B %d}${font}${color}
\
# Cpu, memory, uptime, and load graph #
\
${voffset 294}${goto 40}${color2}Cpu:${color}
${voffset 4}${goto 40}${color2}Mem:${color}
${voffset 4}${goto 40}${color2}Uptime:${color}
${voffset -47}${alignr 39}${color2}${cpu cpu0}%${color}
${voffset 4}${alignr 39}${color2}${memperc}%${color}
${voffset 4}${alignr 39}${color2}${uptime_short}${color}
${voffset -47}${alignc}${color2}${cpubar 5,36}${color}
${voffset 4}${alignc}${color2}${membar 5,36}${color}
${voffset 29}${goto 40}${loadgraph 26,190 F9F9F9 F9F9F9 -l}
\
# The processes section #
\
${voffset 26}${goto 40}${color2}${top_mem name 1}${color}
${voffset 4}${goto 40}${color2}${top_mem name 2}${color}
${voffset 4}${goto 40}${color2}${top_mem name 3}${color}
${voffset 4}${goto 40}${color2}${top_mem name 4}${color}
${voffset 4}${goto 40}${color2}${top_mem name 5}${color}
${voffset -81}${alignc}${color5}${top_mem mem 1}%${color}
${voffset 4}${alignc}${color5}${top_mem mem 2}%${color}
${voffset 4}${alignc}${color5}${top_mem mem 3}%${color}
${voffset 4}${alignc}${color5}${top_mem mem 4}%${color}
${voffset 4}${alignc}${color5}${top_mem mem 5}%${color}
${voffset -81}${alignr 39}${color6}${top_mem mem_res 1}${color}
${voffset 4}${alignr 39}${color6}${top_mem mem_res 2}${color}
${voffset 4}${alignr 39}${color6}${top_mem mem_res 3}${color}
${voffset 4}${alignr 39}${color6}${top_mem mem_res 4}${color}
${voffset 4}${alignr 39}${color6}${top_mem mem_res 5}${color}
${voffset -104}${goto 40}${color9}Proc${color}
${voffset -13}${alignc}${color9}Mem%${color}
${voffset -13}${alignr 39}${color9}Mem${color}
\
# The network section #
\
${if_existing /proc/net/route ppp0}
${voffset -227}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed ppp0}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed ppp0}
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph ppp0 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph ppp0 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup ppp0}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown ppp0}
${else}
${if_existing /proc/net/route ppp1}
${voffset -240}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed ppp1}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed ppp1}
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph ppp1 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph ppp1 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup ppp1}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown ppp1}
${else}
${if_existing /proc/net/route wlp2s1}
${voffset -253}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed wlp2s1}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed wlp2s1}
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph wlp2s1 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph wlp2s1 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup wlp2s1}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown wlp2s1}
${else}
${if_existing /proc/net/route wlp2s0}
${voffset -266}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed wlp2s0}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed wlp2s0}
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph wlp2s0 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph wlp2s0 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup wlp2s0}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown wlp2s0}
${else}
${if_existing /proc/net/route wlan0}
${voffset -279}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed wlan0}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed wlan0}
${voffset 8}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph wlan0 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph wlan0 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup wlan0}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown wlan0}
${else}
${if_existing /proc/net/route wlan1}
${voffset -292}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed wlan1}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed wlan1}
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph wlan1 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph wlan1 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup wlan1}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown wlan1}
${else}
${if_existing /proc/net/route eth1}
${voffset -305}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed eth1}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed eth1}
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph eth1 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph eth1 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup eth1}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown eth1}
${else}
${if_existing /proc/net/route eth0}
${voffset -318}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed eth0}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed eth0}
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph eth0 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph eth0 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup eth0}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown eth0}
${else}
${if_existing /proc/net/route enp0s0}
${voffset -331}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed enp0s0}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed enp0s0}
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph enp0s0 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph enp0s0 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup enp0s0}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown enp0s0}
${else}
${if_existing /proc/net/route enp0s1}
${voffset -344}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed enp0s1}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed enp0s1}
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph enp0s1 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph enp0s1 26,80 F9F9F9 F9F9F9}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup enp0s1}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown enp0s1}
${else}
${voffset -311}${goto 40}${color5}Network disconnected${color}
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/offline.png -p 44,284 -s 16x16}
${endif}${endif}${endif}${endif}${endif}${endif}${endif}${endif}${endif}${endif}
\
# Various images including the icons of the forecast #
\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/pressure2.png -p 224,95 -s 16x16}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/humidity2.png -p 224,115 -s 16x16}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/wind.png -p 224,136 -s 16x16}\
${execi 300 cp -f ~/.conky-weather/icons/weather-icons-light/$(grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==1').png ~/.cache/weather-1.png}${image ~/.cache/weather-1.png -p 41,207 -s 32x32}\
${execi 300 cp -f ~/.conky-weather/icons/weather-icons-light/$(grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==2').png ~/.cache/weather-2.png}${image ~/.cache/weather-2.png -p 119,207 -s 32x32}\
${execi 300 cp -f ~/.conky-weather/icons/weather-icons-light/$(grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==3').png ~/.cache/weather-3.png}${image ~/.cache/weather-3.png -p 195,207 -s 32x32}${font}${voffset -120}\
```

EDIT 3:
Here's what I get with removing `own_window_transparent yes` and giving `own_window_argb_value`  "200"
It now has the black border. I am ultimately trying to get a legible "widget" without the black border.If I change the settings to get rid of the black border, then the picture change on desktop locks into first desktop image as border(instead of black)
[image]

Comment: Do the answers [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/447977/why-isnt-conky-working-right-in-unity-desktop) help you? Also you have commented the `argb_visual` and `argb_value` lines...try uncommenting them.(That was my answer in the link I have given above.)

Comment: I deleted #own_window_argb_visual yes
#own_window_argb_value 0 , but still the problem persists.

Comment: No no. I just said 'uncomment' and you deleted the whole line! You have to remove the # to uncomment a line.

Comment: Ah, ok. Well thanks. I removed the # and edited my question. It leaves a black border now. Can I get rid of the black border?

Comment: Try giving a higher value to `own_window_argb_value` .

Comment: `own_window_type dock` might also help. Also you may want to remove `own_window_transparent yes` .(I mean REMOVE)

Comment: Ok thanks Venki. I tried those things, and a number of other little tweaks. I edited my question.

Comment: Now that you have `own_window_type dock` in your conkyrc remove `own_window_transparent yes` and try giving a higher value to `own_window_argb_value` (Giving higher value to argb_value means your conky will be more opaque. So this should solve your issue.)

Comment: Ok. So I just edited my question with the results. I'm starting to think my only choice is black border or "locked" image border.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out each of these:

```
# Various images #
${execi 300 curl -s "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2418046&u=f" -o ~/.cache/weather.xml}
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/shadow.png -p 4,14 -s 260x591}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/fav-color-1.png -p 20,30 -s 228x61}\
${execi 300 cp -f ~/.conky-weather/icons/weather-photos-7/$(grep "yweather:condition" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*").png ~/.cache/weather.png}${image ~/.cache/weather.png -p 20,91 -s 228x86}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/fav-color-3.png -p 20,177 -s 228x86}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/fav-color-4.png -p 20,263 -s 228x105}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/fav-color-5.png -p 20,368 -s 228x105}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/fav-color-6.png -p 20,473 -s 228x119}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/fav-color-7.png -p 20,478 -s 228x14}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/separator-v.png -p 95,177 -s 1x92}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/separator-v.png -p 172,177 -s 1x92}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/separator-h.png -p 18,369 -s 232x1}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/separator-h.png -p 18,269 -s 232x1}\
```

and these:

```
# Various images including the icons of the forecast #
\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/pressure2.png -p 224,95 -s 16x16}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/humidity2.png -p 224,115 -s 16x16}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Button/God-Mode/wind.png -p 224,136 -s 16x16}\
${execi 300 cp -f ~/.conky-weather/icons/weather-icons-light/$(grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==1').png ~/.cache/weather-1.png}${image ~/.cache/weather-1.png -p 41,207 -s 32x32}\
${execi 300 cp -f ~/.conky-weather/icons/weather-icons-light/$(grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==2').png ~/.cache/weather-2.png}${image ~/.cache/weather-2.png -p 119,207 -s 32x32}\
${execi 300 cp -f ~/.conky-weather/icons/weather-icons-light/$(grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==3').png ~/.cache/weather-3.png}${image ~/.cache/weather-3.png -p 195,207 -s 32x32}${font}${voffset -120}\
```

one at a time, by adding a `#` before each line.  Items will slowly disappear from the overlay.  If you comment all of them before the blackbox disappears, the app is causing the issue, and `own window argb` only supports colors(of which 0 is black), otherwise report the offending line here.(The offending line will be the one in which the black box disappears.)

Comment: I ran through all the lines with adding comment at the beginning. None of them were the offender. The only way I can get the black box to disappear (as of yet) is to go back to my original settings at the beginning of this post. However, I still have the delayed "overlay" change. What do you mean by " the app is causing the issue"?